# How to create a prefix function in swift for a property wrapper just like "$" in SwiftUI

Tags: swift

Is there any **public** API that allows creating access to some certain properties inside a property wrapper? Just like '$' does with 'projectedValue'.

I found that it's possible to create prefix functions, however I'd need to know that a property of a class is wrapped.

It's not valid code but i hope you get the idea.

```
prefix func %<T: Wrapped>(value: T) -> GenericType<T> {
    value.accessWrapper.propertyInsidePropertyWrapper
}
```

so in a class

```
class Test {
    @MyWrapper var pTest = ""
}
```

I could access 'propertyInsidePropertyWrapper' of 'pTest' via '%pTest'.

Comment: Why can't you just use `projectedValue`? Make `projectedValue` return `propertyInsidePropertyWrapper`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this property wrapper:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct MyWrapper<T> {
    var wrappedValue: T
    var foo: Int
}
```

Let's say you want to access `foo` with a prefix. You could just define the projected value as `foo`:

```
var projectedValue: Int { foo }
```

then you can use `$` to access `foo`.

But let's say you actually want the projected value for something else, and would like a new prefix for `foo`. You could create a new operator:

```
prefix operator %

prefix func %<T>(wrapper: MyWrapper<T>) -> Int {
    wrapper.foo
}
```

The problem is, how do we get ourselves a `MyWrapper<T>`? Let's consider:

```
struct Baz {
    @MyWrapper(foo: 777)
    var hello = ""
    
    func f() {
        // we want to access the "foo" of "hello" here
    }
}
```

In this case, we could use `_hello` to access the `MyWrapper<String>` instance:

```
func f() {
    print("Foo: \(%_hello)")
}
```

The catch is, that `_hello` is private, so if you want to access it outside of `Baz`, you need to change the projected value of `MyWrapper` to return `self`,

```
var projectedValue: MyWrapper<T> { self }
```

and do:

```
let baz = Baz()
print("Foo: \(%baz.$hello)")
```

And you would need to think of another prefix for your original projected value. If you are running out of ideas of what prefix to use, perhaps it is a bad idea to use prefixes to access properties. Just do it with names instead:

```
_hello.foo

$hello.foo // outside of the class, with the projected value returning self
```

Also note that the built in `$` prefix is not a prefix *operator*. It is part of the [identifier](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#grammar_identifier), hardcoded in the syntax of Swift as:

```
identifier → property-wrapper-projection
property-wrapper-projection → $ identifier-characters
```

OTOH, a prefix operator must be before a postfix expression (from [Prefix Expressions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID384)):

```
prefix-expression → prefix-operator(opt) postfix-expression
```

Hence why `%baz.$hello`, not `baz.%$hello`.

Comment: Thank you for a prompt and detailed reply.

The reason why I don't want to use $ instead is because I wanted to keep both prefixes. One for one value, another one - for another. 

%vm.$hello - I guess this could work but it does look ugly. Especially the need to create a new extra prefix kills the idea. Perhaps $hello.a $hello.b is a better choice.